# C# Async Await and general async question

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to understand something about async programming in general.
In C# it seems that everyone is now using async await syntatic sugar for async operations that are IO bound.

My question is: Does any operation that is IO bound like a file reading, http request etc that was sync until now can become asnync by writting a wrapper function that is async?

Or since the underlying "old" implementation if it is sync will not help at all?
will the thread that used to wait until now will be released or not?

Anyone?

Comment: There seems to be lot of generalizations here, can you give an example maybe

Comment: Sure. Let say I have a method called:GetHTTPResource that get a hrl as a paramter and return a string after reading this url web content.

This method is synced.

Now I writing a wrapper method looks like this:

public async static GetHTTPResourceAsync
That inside just calling the await GetHTTPResource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping a method that is `sync` with an `async` method can have some benefits. The underlying method will still be synchronous, but you can offload that method to another thread, so the thread that used to wait can now continue it's execution. So in your example, if the UI thread calls the blocking method `GetHTTPResource`, you can achieve UI responsiveness by offloading that method to another thread using an asynchronous wrapper. I recommend you this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), which I think can give you a better understanding of what `async` over `sync` implies. (An [this other](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) covers `sync` over `async`).

With `async` over `sync`, there will still be a thread blocked. That is the reason why it makes little sense in case of a web application, using asynchronous wrappers for synchronous functions has no performance benefits. Quoting the aforementioned article (emphasis mine):

> The ability to invoke a synchronous method asynchronously does nothing
>   for scalability, because **you’re typically still consuming the same
>   amount of resources** you would have if you’d invoked it synchronously
>   (in fact, you’re using a bit more, since there’s overhead incurred to
>   scheduling something ), **you’re just using different resources to do
>   it**, e.g. a thread from a thread pool instead of the specific thread
>   you were executing on.  The scalability benefits touted for
>   asynchronous implementations are achieved by decreasing the amount of
>   resources you use, and that needs to be baked into the implementation
>   of an asynchronous method… it’s not something achieved by wrapping
>   around it.

For instante, in case of an [ASP.NET application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45), fully `async` code allows threads to process new requests while other requests are waiting for I/O operations to complete, thus achieving higher scalability. On the other hand, if the code has underlying synchronous methods for I/O operations, there will be threads blocked that won't be able to do anything but wait until these operations complete. So `async` over `sync` usually has no benefit in case of web applications.

Comment: The essence of [the article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/): "Asynchronous methods should not be exposed purely for the purpose of offloading. The only asynchronous methods that should be exposed are those that have scalability benefits over their synchronous counterparts."

Comment: thanks. But another question - you mentioned that the UI thread will be released. But I still dont understand something. there is a thread that is still blocked right? does this means that in a server API that is not UI/UX it has no benefit?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias True, although that conclusion of [the article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) relates specifically to developing libreries and the API surface they should provide. I mean it is a conclusion of the `async` over `sync` understanding that the OP was looking for.
@Pinidbest I have edited my answer to address the question on your comment.

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias - Thanks you so much for answering. I want to keep the discussion and ask further: in case of the web application sample you mentioned, doesnt the runtime splits the threads into UI thread and IO threads in some way to that the UI threads can be free to get other requests? are you saying that always async wrapper above sync code will not increase throughput in any case?  (I understand about server code such as web API but maybe we are missing something about UI like in windows apps or web apps?

Comment: @Pinidbest I didn't mention anything about web application samples. I just highlighted the core point of a linked article.  About your question: no, AFAIK async over sync does not increase throughput.

Comment: Async over sync is an *antipattern*. For server apps, async over sync actually *reduces* both throughput and scalability.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, your sync function can become async, for example in HTTP Request you can change your Sync function

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(string requestUri, Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders)
    {
        return HttpRequestFactory.Get(requestUri, requestHeaders);
    }
```

Calling function

```
var result =  HttpClient.GetRequest(requestUri, _request, _requestHeaders)
```

you will change this into async like this

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(string requestUri, Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders)
   {
            return await HttpRequestFactory.Get(requestUri, requestHeaders);
   }
```

calling function to

```
var result = HttpClient.GetRequest(requestUri, _request, _requestHeaders).Result;
```

Hope so this will help to you..

Comment: the technical part i understand - but still. The underlying method is sync. the Get.Doesnt this means that a thread will still be hanged there?

Comment: you can remove result at the end of `var result = HttpClient.GetRequest(requestUri, _request, _requestHeaders)`